# How to turn it on emulator Android-studio

Tags: bios, sony, vt-x

Android Studio requires connection to the emulator, but an error is displayed: "Haxm is not installed" and the emulator does not want to work, but VT-x is included in the bios and is supported on this model. The Sony Vaio model is SVF1521X1RW, the bios version is R0210DA. I hope you can help me solve this problem)

I spent a lot of time searching for information, and everything is useless (unfortunately, the Sony BIOS is heavily trimmed).

1. There is no need to flash the bios, VT-x works